# Possible to use jQuery without IDs?

Tags: c#, jquery, forms, razor, ids

I am working on a piece of code where it appears as if though jQuery accesses an element by ID *without* the element actually having an ID. In the form this is what I have:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.IsEBSToBeCreated, new { disabled = "disabled", @checked = "checked" })
```

No IDs in the surrounding `<div>` but in the script I see this:

```
if ($("#ddlStatus option:selected").text() == 'Active') {
                $("#IsEBSToBeCreated").prop("disabled", false);
            }
```

How is jQuery using `#IsEBSToBeCreated` without a matching ID in the `.cshtml` file itself.

Comment: Have you looked at the markup generated by `Html.CheckBoxFor` ?

Comment: Examine your rendered HTML. The ID *must* exist for it to be used.

Answer (score 1):

Using the hint from @madreflection I looked at the documentation and [markup generated](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-checkbox-checkboxfor) by the `Html.CheckBoxFor` and indeed it generates an input element with an `#IsEBSToBeCreated` ID.

> Thank you